# Copying sprite metafiles - terrible thing to do?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have sliced an image img1.png into multiple sprites in the Unity editor. As I didn't know any other way how to copy the slicing information into a similar image img2.png, I copied the file img1.png.meta, renamed it to img2.png.meta, and renamed all "img1" strings inside the meta file to "img2".

I am now starting to worry that I have done something like f*cked-up necromancy. It appears, there is something like an *object global and local id* that is stored in the metafile as well. And there is also something stored in the /Library/metadata folder. Anyway, if I open both metafiles in a text editor now, they happen to have their global ids magically different again. Everything else inside the metafile seems to remain in the way I changed it.

**My questions are:**
Should I worry? If so, is there a way to undo my wrongdoing? (There is more than one file I have brutally renamed this way.)
And, is there a way to perform this kind of necromancy rightly and safely?

Comment: The guid is used by Unity to identify an asset. That's stored in the meta file and in any other assets that need to know about that asset. When you copy and rename a meta file the next time you open Unity it will reassign one of the guids to fix the duplication, but you don't get to pick which one. Sometimes it hurts nothing, sometimes all of the associations to img1 now point to img2 since it has the original guid and img1 was reassigned. Feel free to copy other settings in the meta file but don't mess with guids or you will be sad someday.

Comment: @Retired Ninja: So, if the sprites work fine while testing the game in the editor, everything is fine? I need to know whether I have to reimport the sprites or not.

Comment: If the right sprite is attached to the right prefabs and such and you don't see any weirdness you should be fine. If you have your assets forced to text in the editor settings and use source control you can usually see if a bunch of guids changed in your assets.

Comment: Retired Ninja is saying that you now don't know if img1 or img2 is the original and which is the "new copy", i.e. which is now used across old assets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unity usually manages to fix these for you.

Even If you would have removed all the metas, Unity would still manage to open, (with lost information such as image slicing), then rebuild the metas.

This means that if you don't see a problem in the editor, you should be fine, because unity fixed it properly.

Now to ensure you don't have to edit the metas manually, you could do the following:

- **inside** unity editor: Copy the image with the slicing you want (that creates a new file with proper slicing with a proper meta)
- **inside** unity editor: Rename this file with the name of your new image
- **ouside** unity editor: replace the renamed copy with your new image that has the same name

Go back in unity editor

Comment: in the editor, there is a windows called the "Project Window" where you can see the files in the asset folder (see https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/interface-essentials/project-window). From there, select the image and click ctrl+d to make a duplicate